# android- Delete an item SwipeListView Error

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem and I can't solve it. Thanks for your help.

I tried to delete an item on `SwipeMenuListView` but I couldn't do that.
Here is my code;

```
 list= (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    groups = new UserData(getApplication()).getUserGroups();
    if (groups == null)
        groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, groups.toArray(new String[0]));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


list.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    try {
                        groups.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.d("TAG","onMenuClickListener"+index+" position is "+ position);
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TAG","error  " + e);
                    }

            }
            // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
            return false;
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(GroupActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("GRUPID", groups.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

When I tried to remove an item, the item didn't delete and second time push button an error occurred;

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1.

I think the item is deleted but it keeps appearing.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please try this `groups.remove(position-1);`

Comment: yeap I tried your suggestion but isn't work. When I looked in debug mode, selected item deleted but didnt refresh listview.

Comment: there is no method like notifyItemRemoved. :( I think notifyItemRemoved method use in recylerview